# How to encoder Csv with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, csv, serialization, components

I'm using serializer component's symfony, and there was an example to serialize and Object to JSON format, next:

```
    $encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
    $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());

    $person = new \AppBundle\Entity\Person();
    $person->setName('foo');
    $person->setAge(99);
    $person->setSportsman(false);

    // return new JsonResponse($person); // empty

    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

    /**
     * 1 param - object to be serialized
     * 2 param - proper encoder, in this case JsonEncoder
     * @var [type]
     */
    $jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($person, 'json');

    return new Response($jsonContent);
```

The above example returns something like this:

```
{"id":null,"age":99,"name":"foo","sportsman":false}
```

But I want know **How to do the same**, to `CSV` instead `JSON`

Comment: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-csv-and-yaml-encoders-for-serializer???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSV and YAML encoder were added since Symfony 3.2

```
// instantiation, when using it as a component
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\CsvEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

$serializer = new Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer()], [new CsvEncoder()]);

// instantiation, when using it inside the Symfony framework
$serializer = $container->get('serializer');

// encoding contents in CSV format
$serializer->encode($data, 'csv');

// decoding CSV contents
$data = $serializer->decode(file_get_contents('data.csv'), 'csv');
```

You can find more info there: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-csv-and-yaml-encoders-for-serializer

Comment: I tried the same codes, but got an empty array.
What is use of first $serializer variable?